# Dapper object plus context

Tags: c#, dapper

Code:

```
   class ComplicatedObject {
            public int? TaskTypeId { get; set; }
            public int?[] CountTypeIds { get; set; }
            public int?[] EquipmentTypeIds { get; set; }
            public int? TaskBlockId { get; set; }
            public int? TeamId { get; set; }
            public string DriverId { get; set; }
            public int? TaskStatusId { get; set; }
            public string EventType { get; set; }
            public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
            public string County { get; set; }
            public string Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

Currently I am doing:

```
            var param = new
            {
                Id = id,
                TaskTypeId = complicatedObjectInstance.TaskTypeId,
                CountTypeIds = complicatedObjectInstance.CountTypeIds,
                EquipmentTypeIds = complicatedObjectInstance.EquipmentTypeIds,
                TaskBlockId = complicatedObjectInstance.TaskBlockId,
                TeamId = complicatedObjectInstance.TeamId,
                DriverId = complicatedObjectInstance.DriverId,
                TaskStatusId = complicatedObjectInstance.TaskStatusId,
                EventType = complicatedObjectInstance.EventType,
                StartDate = complicatedObjectInstance.StartDate,
                EndDate = complicatedObjectInstance.EndDate,
                County = complicatedObjectInstance.County,
                Tags = complicatedObjectInstance.Tag
            };
    ExecuteQuery(sql, params)
```

Where the object that dapper is getting is basically just the Id plus ComplicatedObject .

I want to do something like

```
ExecuteQuery(sql, new { Id = id, complicatedObjectInstance})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your object to a dictionary and then add additional props to it.

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object value)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType()).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToDictionary(property => property.Name, property => property.GetValue(value));
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestDictionary()
{
    var param = new TestClass { Bar = "Bar", Foo = "Foo" }.ToDictionary();
    param.Add("Id", 99);

    using (
        var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=foo"))
    {
        var result = conn.Query("select Foo = @Foo, Id = @Id", param).First();
        Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(99));
    }
}
```